# Sublime Text 3 - compile and run c++ program(the path contains space) in terminal

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext3

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I use Sublime Text 3, and I can compile c++ program and run it in terminal.
The following is the script.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "RunInShell",
            "shell": true,
            "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name};echo;  echo Press ENTER to continue; read line;exit; exec bash\"'"]
        }
    ]    
}
```

BUT, **when the path of c++ program contains space**(like `/algorithms/Search in Rotated Sorted Array`), the script doesn't work!

`bash: /media/algorithms/Search: No such file or directory` shows in the terminal, when I using RunInShell.

I am trying to modify the script, like insert single quotes.

`"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"'${file_path}/${file_base_name}';echo;  echo Press ENTER to continue; read line;exit; exec bash\"'"]`

But it doesn't work .

I wonder how to modify the script to make it work well.

Comment: You probably need additional quoting around the `${file_path}/${file_base_name}` part.

Comment: Your idea is right, but the additional quoting around this part matches the front quotes.So it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If we look at the documentation on Build Systems, we see that we can use snippet substitution in the variables used in the build system.](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#placeholders-for-variables)

Therefore, we can [escape each space to a backslash and a space, for use in Bash](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10954). It may be easier to play around with it outside the build system first, for example by typing the following in ST's (Python) console:

```
import os.path; file_path = '/algorithms/Search in Rotated Sorted Array'; file_name = os.path.basename(file_path); sublime.expand_variables(r'${file_path/ /\\ /g}/${file_base_name/ /\\ /g}', { 'file_path': os.path.dirname(file_path), 'file': file_path, 'file_name': file_name, 'file_extension': os.path.splitext(file_name)[1], 'file_base_name': os.path.splitext(file_name)[0], 'packages': sublime.packages_path() })
```

Note that the above includes more variables than we actually need, but doesn't actually include [all the variables available from the build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#build-system-variables), but it is enough for this example and they can easily be added if you want to experiment further. Check the [ST API Reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) for more info, specifically the missing items are part of the `Window` class.

Anyway, the output we get from that is:

> ```
> '/algorithms/Search\\ in\\ Rotated\\ Sorted\\ Array'
> ```

(Remember that this is a Python string, so two slashes is an escape code that represents a single slash.)

So what we see here is `${file_path/ /\\\\ /g}`. What this tells ST, is to take the value of the `file_path` variable and run a regex substitution on it. It should replace a space with a literal slash followed by a space. The `/g` at the end is the global regex modifier flag, to tell it to not stop at the first match/replacement, to make sure it replaces all spaces.

Now, to plug that into your build system:

```
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path/ /\\\\ /g}/${file_base_name/ /\\\\ /g};echo;  echo Press ENTER to continue; read line;exit; exec bash\"'"]
```

Note that we have 4 slashes - both in the Python code I showed to test with and the JSON string. This is because the first two slashes is an escape sequence that tells JSON/Python to use a literal slash. Then we want to do the same again, so that the regex pattern will use a literal slash.

Comment: cool! Your explanation is clear. And it works well after modifying. Thanks!